# Equivalence relations on well-orderable sets

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations, well-orders

Let $W$ be a well-orderable set. Show that $W/\equiv$ is well-orderable for any equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $W.$

Here, $W/\equiv$ is the set of all equivalence classes aka the *quotient.* A relation $\equiv$ is called an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

I want to show this within ZF set theory. I have the definition of a well-orderable set too. Please can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: @DMcMor If the equivalence relation is called $\equiv$, the quotient should be called $W/\equiv$. What are you asking?

Comment: What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Let $[a_1]$ and $[a_2]$ be two equivalence classes such that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the smallest representatives of each of the equivalence classes respectively (which can be done since $W$ is well-orderable). Then define a well-ordering on the equivalence classes via:

$$[a_1] \leq [a_2] \iff a_1 \leq a_2.$$

(i.e. the equivalence classes induce a partition, and you can sort each subset in the partition via their smallest element)

Comment: You mean equivalence classes, not equivalent classes, right?

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the typo.

Comment: In other words $[x]<^*[y]$ iff $\min [x]<\min [y]$.............+1